# Insane Integration

Tags: integration

$$\int \frac{x^{2018 } dx }{ \sum_{n=0}^{n=2018} \frac{x^n}{n!}}  = m! x - m! \log(P(x)) +c$$

I need to find 'm' and 'P(x)'

I considered differentiating it and trying to solve but that too seems impossible because you'd to deal with btoh $P'(x)$ and $P(x)$

p.s: this is not a joke integral,  don't give me horseshoe integration lol

Comment: Could $P(x)$ possibly be the denominator of the integrand?

Comment: yes that was one of the options but how would that help us

Comment: $$\int \frac{x^{2018}}{ \sum_{n=0}^{2018} \frac{x^n}{n!}}\,dx=\int \frac{e^{-x}\,x^{2018}}{ e^{-x}\,\sum_{n=0}^{2018} \frac{x^n}{n!}}\,dx,$$ and the numerator is $-2018!$ times the derivative of the denominator.

Comment: By the way it’s set up I feel like maybe if you add the other 2017 terms to the top then subtract them off you could split the integral up into 1 - the sum on the bottom up the the first 2017 terms / the denominator. Then from there you could do something with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

If $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{2018}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
 Then $\displaystyle f'(x)=f(x)-\frac{x^{2018}}{2018!}$

So in the numerator of integrand $\displaystyle x^{2018}=2018!f(x)-2018!f'(x)$

Comment: how did you figure it out?

Comment: @DDD4C4U Just observed it.....

Answer (score 0):

Noticed the transformation below:
$$\frac{1}{2018!}\cdot\frac{x^{2018}}{\sum_{n=0}^{2018}\frac{x^n}{n!}}=1-\frac{\sum_{n=0}^{2017}\frac{x^n}{n!}}{\sum_{n=0}^{2018}\frac{x^n}{n!}}=1-\frac{(\sum_{n=0}^{2018}\frac{x^n}{n!})'}{\sum_{n=0}^{2018}\frac{x^n}{n!}}$$

Comment: Exactly what I commented sweet! Thanks for writing our!